# Modules vs Class memory difference

Tags: javascript

I have some methods and properties that I would like to be available to other files in my JS application.

I see I have 2 options, I can either have a class:

```
class MusicTile {
    
    artistTitle = find('someProperty')

    play() {
        // Some logic
    }

}
```

And then do `let myTile = new MusicTiles`

Or just export like so

```
let artistTitle = find('someProperty')

function play() {
        // Some logic
}

export { play }
```

And just `import { * } from './musicTile.js'`

I'm curious which of the 2 is better to use. I don't really need to instantiate MusicTile, I just want the properties from there so I guess a plain old export is fine. But is there something else to consider?

Also how is memory usage between the two, I guess the export doesn't do anything unless I call the methods in there. But the class approach (at least how it is with the `artistTitle = find('someProperty')` outside a method) would call `find()` as soon as I do `new MusicTile` so consume more memory?

Comment: These are two concepts known as functional programming and object-oriented programming. They're two different design patterns. and each design pattern has its own benefits on the other. some people don't like the object-oriented programming paradigm and they claim that it adds too much unnecessary complexity. but that's just wrong because it depends on the problem, sometimes its better to follow the object oriented paradigm and sometimes compositional and functional programming is better

Comment: If it's just as simple as you described, it does not require that much thinking. Which pattern are you following in your application? If you're using classes all over your code, make it a class. If not, make it a function. it's a matter of a personal preference and choice in the end.

Comment: Unless you plan on instantiating multiple instances, using a class doesn't really gain you anything.  Memory usage is not going to be much different, but without a class maybe slightly less.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. So the above is simplified and its a new piece of work, so not using either at the moment, just planning. If there's no difference in terms of memory usage etc then I'll guess I'll just stick to the simple exports approach.

Comment: Imports/exports handles all types of symbols, what you appear to be asking about is mechanisms for modularity and encapsulation.  I don’t think you need be overly concerned about memory requirements unless you know your target is particularly constrained or by the scale of your solution.